# How to solve $\int e^{-\sqrt{x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have this integral:

$$\int e^{-\sqrt{x}}dx.$$

This is what I have done:

$$\int e^{-\sqrt{x}}dx = \int \frac{1}{e^{\sqrt{x}}} dx$$

I Tried to solve it by substitution:

$$t = \sqrt{x}$$
$$ t^2 = x$$
$$ 2d = dx$$

So:

$$\int \frac{1}{e^{\sqrt{x}}} dx = \int \frac{1}{e^t} 2t$$

Then:

$$2\int \frac{t}{e^t}dt$$

How should I proceed?

Comment: It is $2t \ dt=dx$ not $2 \ d=dx$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Your edit maybe hide, that the OP has some fundamental problems with substitution.

Comment: @calculus It seemed to me that he got the integrand right ($t$ was there), but ok, I'll roll back.

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{^{\Large-\sqrt[n]x}}~dx ~=~ n!$

Comment: If you differentialte both sides of $t^2=x$ you get $2t \ dt=1 \ dx$ Then $\int \frac{1}{e^{\sqrt{x}}} dx$ becomes $\int \frac{1}{e^{t}} 2t \ dt$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thanks for the roll back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing $2\int e^{-t}tdt$, we can use the integration by parts formula $\int fg'=fg-\int f'g$ to get
\begin{equation*}
-2e^{-t}t+2\int e^{-t}dt.
\end{equation*}
Use the substitution $u=-t$ to get
\begin{equation*}
-2e^{-t}t-2\int e^udu.
\end{equation*}
Integrate and substitute back.

Answer (score 1):

See the integrand as $te^{-t}$ and integrate by parts.

Comment: Do you mean that he must see it as $t\,d\left[-e^{-t}\right]$ ?

Comment: Yes. Then integrating by parts, it is just an exponential to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It will be more useful to apply the subsitution $t=-\sqrt{x}$. Then apply integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

By parts,
$$\int e^{-\sqrt x}dx=\int2\sqrt xe^{-\sqrt x}\frac{dx}{2\sqrt x}=-2\sqrt x e^{-\sqrt x}+\int2e^{-\sqrt x}\frac{dx}{2\sqrt x}=-2\sqrt x e^{-\sqrt x}-2e^{-\sqrt x}.$$